# Using variables in perl command with bash

Tags: bash, ssh, quoting

I can't seems to see why `$crypt` is empty here

```
#!/bin/bash
pass=$(pwgen -1 -n 8)
salt=$(pwgen -1 -n 5) 
crypt=$(perl -le 'print crypt($pass, $salt)')
user=deluge_$(pwgen -s 5 1)
echo crypt: $crypt # no output
echo pass: $pass #work
echo salt : $salt #work
echo $(perl -le 'print crypt($pass, $salt)') # no output

perl -le 'print crypt(Ab3choot, Oa3ah)' # works
```

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `bash`, variables won't be expanded when put inside single quotes, use double quotes instead:

```
crypt=$(perl -le "print crypt("$pass", "$salt")")
```

Now the `bash` variables, `$pass` and `$salt` should be expanded expectedly.

Also almost always, it is a good idea to quote the variables to avoid word splitting and filename expansion.

Comment: You aren't quoting the variables; you're expanding them unquoted with their values concatenated with the adjacent quoted strings. `perl -le 'my $pass=shift; my $salt=shift; print crypt($pass, $salt)' "$pass" "$salt"` would be safer.

Comment: Note that passing the `-w` flag to `perl` would have made this problem more clear: it would have warned that the `$pass` and `$salt` variables are only used once.